# DBPedia: SPARQL query on field starting with literal

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get the respective DBPedia entry for a list of companies. I can't figure out how to do approximate matches.
Example: "Audi" is called "Audi AG" in DBPedia and "Novartis" is called "Novartis International AG" (foaf:name). How do I search for entries with rdf:type = dbo:Company and name closest to whatever I provide?

I'm using SPARQL as the query language. (But I'm open to change if there is an advantage.)

```
select ?company
where {
  ?company foaf:name "Novartis"@en.
  ?company a dbo:Company.
}
LIMIT 100
```

I get no hit but http://dbpedia.org/page/Novartis should be found. Matching the beginning of the name might be good enough to get this.

Comment: SPARQL is [a language](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), with [many functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/Expressions_and_Functions#Functions_on_Strings), and DBpedia is hosted on an engine with [many extensions](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksSPARQL11BuiltInF)... Not to mention built-in tools that can help you build more queries based on one you [build within it](http://dbpedia.org/fct/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for best match to a string with SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671325/query-for-best-match-to-a-string-with-sparql)

Comment: Why do you think `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Novartis` should be found with your query? The `foaf:name` of this resource is `"Novartis International AG"@en` and only its `rdfs:label` is `"Novartis"@en` - anything beyond exact matching of existing literals in the RDF triples can only be solved by some `FILTER` with one of the string functions (`regex`, `contains`, `strstarts`) or some extended functions not part of the SPARQL 1.1 standard but triple store dependent.

Comment: a more complete check for exact match on DBpedia is to consider redirects also known as surface forms or synonyms of resources: `?company ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/(rdfs:label|foaf:name)  "Novartis"@en.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DBpedia, the best option might be to use the **`bif:contains` full-text search** pseudo property:

```
SELECT ?company {
  ?company a dbo:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name.
  ?name bif:contains "Novartis"@en.
}
```

This feature is specific to the Virtuoso database that powers the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint.

If you want to stick to **standard SPARQL**, to **match at the beginning** of the name only:

```
SELECT ?company {
  ?company a dbo:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name.
  FILTER strStarts(?name, "Novartis")
}
```

Unlike the full-text feature, this version cannot make use of a text index, so it is slower.

If you want a more **flexible match**:

```
SELECT ?company {
  ?company a dbo:Company.
  ?company foaf:name ?name.
  FILTER contains(lCase(?name), lCase("Novartis"))
}
```

This will find a case-insensitive match anywhere in the name.

Comment: Thanks @cygri! I went for the first approach using "bif:contains" and it works perfectly!